# Is it possible to have a single Gson-based method to deserialize maps with values from different classes?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, guava

I have two methods that are virtually identical, both reading a map serialized as JSON. These are maps with multiple values per key, so I am converting the maps to guava `Multimap`. And I am using `Gson` for serializing and deserializing these maps. The relevant parts of the code follows:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                             .setPrettyPrinting()
                             .create();
```

Now, the nearly identical deserialization methods are:

```
private static Multimap<String, FirstClass> readFirstClassMMap(Path jsonFile, Type mapType) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Set<FirstClass>> map = GSON.fromJson(Files.newBufferedReader(jsonFile), mapType);
    Multimap<String, FirstClass> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (String key : map.keySet())
        mmap.putAll(key, map.get(key));

    return mmap;
}

private static Multimap<String, SecondClass> readSecondClassMMap(Path jsonFile, Type mapType) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Set<SecondClass>> map = GSON.fromJson(Files.newBufferedReader(jsonFile), mapType);
    Multimap<String, FirstClass> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (String key : map.keySet())
        mmap.putAll(key, map.get(key));

    return mmap;
}
```

The second argument, `mapType`, is created just before calling these methods as follows:

```
Type maptype = new TypeToken<Map<String, Set<FirstClass>>>() {}.getType();
```

I would like to have a single method instead of a new method for every custom class I have. But here, I got really confused as I tried using reflection to identify whether the values are of `FirstClass` or `SecondClass`.

The custom classes (`FirstClass` and `SecondClass`) are not related in any way.

Is it possible to have a single deserialization method in this scenario? If yes, how should I proceed?

Comment: I think you may have some typos in your posted code, you should probably verify that it compiles so we can play with it a bit.

Comment: Java generics comes to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could post a SSCCE with sample classes and input files, it would be extremely helpful. Something like this may work, but without knowing a bit more about what sort of input this is expected to deal with, I can't be sure if it will work.

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
                                                  .setPrettyPrinting()
                                                  .create();

private static <T> Multimap<String, T> readAnyClassMMap(Path jsonFile, Type typeOfT) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Set<T>> map = GSON.fromJson(Files.newBufferedReader(jsonFile, Charset.defaultCharset()), typeOfT);
    Multimap<String, T> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        mmap.putAll(key, map.get(key));
    }
    return mmap;
}
```